# C++ SFINAE with decltype: substitution failure becomes an error?

Tags: c++, sfinae

This code works:

```
// Code A
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct S {
    template <typename Iter, typename = typename enable_if<is_constructible<T, decltype(*(declval<Iter>()))>::value>::type>
    S(Iter) { cout << "S(Iter)" << endl; }

    S(int) { cout << "S(int)" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    S<int> s1(v.begin()); // stdout: S(Iter)
    S<int> s2(1);         // stdout: S(int)
}
```

But this code below doesn't work. In the code below, I merely want to inherit `std::enable_if`, so the class `is_iter_of` will have member typedef `type` if the selected version of `std::enable_if` has member typedef `type`.

```
// Code B
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template <typename Iter, typename Target>
struct is_iter_of : public enable_if<is_constructible<Target, decltype(*(declval<Iter>()))>::value> {}

template <typename T>
struct S {
    template <typename Iter, typename = typename is_iter_of<Iter, T>::type>
    S(Iter) { cout << "S(Iter)" << endl; }

    S(int) { cout << "S(int)" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    S<int> s1(v.begin());
    S<int> s2(1);   // this is line 22, error
}
```

Error message:

```
In instantiation of 'struct is_iter_of<int, int>':
12:30:   required by substitution of 'template<class Iter, class>     S<T>::S(Iter) [with Iter = int; <template-parameter-1-2> = <missing>]'
22:16:   required from here
8:72: error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
```

The error message is bewildering: of course I want the template substitution to fail.. so the correct constructor could be selected. Why didn't SFINAE work in `Code B`? If `invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')` offends the compiler, the compiler should have issued a same error for `Code A` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is you're trying to extend from `std::enable_if`, but the expression you put inside the enable if may be invalid. Since you are using a class that inherit form that, the class you instanciate inherit from an invalid expression, hence the error.

An easy solution for having a name for your `enable_if` expression would be to use an alias instead of a class:

```
template <typename Iter, typename Target>
using is_iter_of = enable_if<is_constructible<Target, decltype(*(declval<Iter>()))>::value>;
```

SFINAE will still work as expected with an alias.

This is because instancing an alias is part of the function you try to apply SFINAE on. With inheritance, the expression is part of the class being instanciated, not the function. This is why you got a hard error.

The thing is, the is multiple ways SFINAE is applied in your case. Let's take a look at where SFINAE can happen:

```
enable_if< //             here -------v
    is_constructible<Target, decltype(*(declval<Iter>()))>::value
>::type
//  ^--- here
```

Indeed, SFINAE will happen because `enable_if::type` will not exist if the bool parameter is false, causing SFINAE.

But if you look closely, another type might not exist: `decltype(*(std::declval<Iter>()))`. If `Iter` is `int`, asking for the type of the star operator makes no sense. So SFINAE if applied there too.

Your solution with inheritance would have work if every class you send as `Iter` had the `*` operator available. Since with `int` it does not exist, you are sending a non existing type to `std::is_constructible`, making the whole expression forming the base class invalid.

With the alias, the whole expression of using `std::enable_if` is subject to apply SFINAE. Whereas the base class approach will only apply SFINAE on the result of `std::enable_if`.

Comment: Uh.. stupid me. Using typedef (and if not applicable, template alias) should always be the **first** choice for tasks that are aimed to shorten expressions.

Comment: So.. based on your answer, am I correct to conclude that template overload resolution won't take place in the inheritance list? I thought the compiler should be able to select the correct (i.e. valid) version of `enable_if` in the inheritance list.

Comment: @user8385554 yes it can. But if the expression inside the parameters of `enable_if` causes an error, the base class simply falls apart. But if every tyle you send to `S` constructor had the `*` operator, the base class would work and you'll end up with a class that conditionally has  a typedef in it. But if `*` operator don't exist, how can you evaluate `is_constructible` if the second parameter is not a valid expression?

Comment: This is where SFINAE is applied in addition of the `enable_if` SFINAE. You class solution assumed that SFINAE were only applied by the `enable_if` result, but in reality, SFINAE is applied to the whole expression, including the expressions forming the type parameter you send to `enable_if`. The alias permit SFINAE to be applied to the whole result of the aliased expression.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the expression `*int` (`*(declval<Iter>())`) is invalid, so your template fails. You need to another level of templating, so I suggest a void_t approach:

- make `is_iter_of` by a concept-lite that derives from `true_type` or `fals_type`
- use `enable_if` within the definition of your class to enable the iterator constructor.

The key thing to understand is that your constructor before needed a type for `typename is_iter_of<Iter, T>::type` except that your `enable_if` in the `struct is_iter_of` caused the entire thing to be ill-formed. And since there was no fall-back template you had a compiler error.

```
template<class...>
using voider = void;

template <typename Iter, typename Target, typename = void>
struct is_iter_of : std::false_type{};

template <typename Iter, typename Target>
struct is_iter_of<Iter, Target, voider<decltype(*(declval<Iter>()))>> : std::is_constructible<Target, decltype(*(declval<Iter>()))> {};

template <typename T>
struct S {
    template <typename Iter, typename std::enable_if<is_iter_of<Iter, T>::value, int>::type = 0>
    S(Iter) { cout << "S(Iter)" << endl; }

    S(int) { cout << "S(int)" << endl; }
};
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3tyleQ3P26PVhO4m) (C++11)

---

#### What's happening

The additional `voider` makes the template specialization not preferred if `*(declval<Iter>())` is an ill-formed expression (`*int`) and so the fallback base template (`std::false_type`) is chosen.

Else, it will derived from ``` std::is_constructible``. In other words, it can still derive from ```std::false_type`if the expression is well-formed but it's not constructibe, and`true_type` otherwise.

Comment: In Code A's `S s2(1)` instantiation, the constructor template also needs "type" member and `enable_if<..>` doesn't have that member. That is the reason why this template constructor is deleted in the first place (so the second, "normal" constructor is selected). Why can't Code B do the same? What did you mean by "fall-back"? Thanks for your workaround, BTW:)

Comment: Note that unused template parameters are ignored in gcc (for a lot of versions, I know that gcc all the way to 7 ignores unnamed template parameters erroneously).  Use the `make_void` trick to avoid this

Comment: Also, it should also be mentioned that the template instantiation from the base class is out of the current context of the substitution and therefore fails.